# Quaternion calculation

Tags: quaternions

```
Quaternion[0, Cos[Pi/20]/Sqrt[2], Sin[Pi/20]/Sqrt[2], 0] ** 
 Quaternion[0, 1, 0, 0] ** 
 Quaternion[0, -Cos[Pi/20]/Sqrt[2], -Sin[Pi/20]/Sqrt[2], 0]
```

this should produce a table of real numbers, but, at least for me, the result appears to include a very small imaginary component.

```
Quaternion[0, (-(1/4))*(-1)^(9/10)*(1 + (-1)^(1/5)), (1/8)*(-1 + 
    Sqrt[5]), 0]
```

I believe the result is wrong, but grateful for any suggestions of how to fix it (or is it possible that my version has become corrupted - do others get the same result ?)

Comment: That's rounding error. What if you replace the `N[]` with `Simplify[]`?

Comment: thanks - I was just using N[] to show that the i was very small. Simplify still has the small i showing. What's confusing me is that the logic within Quaternions.m is matrix multiplication, i doesnt get a look in. I'm using the elements for plotting, so can correct it with Re[], but would rather the calculation worked as expected.

Comment: I've amended the above to remove any confusion from using N[ ]

Comment: What result are you expecting? Possibly this would be better? `In[2322]:= RootReduce[(-(1/4))*(-1)^(9/10)*(1 + (-1)^(1/5))]

Out[2322]= Root[5 - 80 #1^2 + 256 #1^4 &, 4]` Or this `In[2323]:= ToRadicals[%]

Out[2323]= 1/4 Sqrt[1/2 (5 + Sqrt[5])]` ?

Comment: As for obtaining the result, that is pretty difficult in the absence of any definitions for `Quaternion`. This should go without saying (but I said it anyway).

Comment: I am using the Quaternion definition as per the Quaternions Package in Mathematica. The result for the second piece should be 0.475528, but is coming out as 0.475528 - 2.77556*10^-17 I

Comment: Did you even try my advice of avoiding `N[]` for the time being and using `Simplify[]` or `FullSimplify[]` instead? What did you see?

Comment: Yes I did, please see my response above. the small imaginary part of the answer persists. For practical purposes I'm now using Re[] to extract the real parts, but multiplying quaternions with real coordinates should not produce a coordinate with an imaginary component.

Comment: But FullSimplify does provide a result with real parts - thanks. If I understand, N[] evaluates the parts separately, then totals, giving a small imaginary residual. I needed FullySimplify[] to fully expand all the elements, at which point the imaginary part cancels.

Comment: My gosh, I didn't even realize we had a `Quaternions` package. Live and learn.

Comment: @Daniel, I think it's been there since at least version 3… ;)

Comment: G Taylor: as I said, this is floating point arithmetic error at work. That's the reason for telling you to postpone the use of `N[]`; now that you're sure (through symbolic means) that there was no imaginary part after all, it is now safe to use `Chop[]`.

Comment: @J.M. I probably once knew about it and forgot. I've also been here since at least version 3 (actually since just before 2.1). I wonder if it is designed in a way that is reasonable by current standards though.

Comment: @Daniel, objectively it could use a little spit and polish, but a good portion of the code looks timeless to me. :)